# Error "Failed to resolve package" when trying to install Azure package into Sencha Touch application

Tags: extjs, azure, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, azure-mobile-services

I am building a Sencha Touch app for my client and going to attempt to use Windows Azure mobile services to support push notifications.

I generated the app using `generate app` command.

I have added the package dependency to my app.json file:

```
"requires": [
 {
      "name": "Basic",
      "requires": [
          "touch-azure"
      ]
  }
]
```

Then I do a build using the command:

```
sencha app build
```

The build works fine, except that I get a warning saying that it "Failed to resolve package 'Basic'".

I assumed it must be because I hadn't installed the package into the local repository, so then I installed it with this command:

```
sencha package get touch-azure
```

This command worked fine and I can see the package has been installed in:

```
C:\Users\[username]\sencha\bin\Sencha\Cmd\repo\pkgs\touch-azure
```

I then attempted another build, but still get the warning:

```
[WRN] Failed to resolve package Basic
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what else I can try?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this on the Sencha Forums, since this exact question was asked there:
  - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?280347-Installation-of-the-touch-azure-package-fails